# Navigation smaller on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I make the navigation bar go smaller on scroll like this site?
This one is going really smooth.

https://websight.nl/

I know it is probably done in JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. You need to apply a class on scroll to a particular height and in CSS you have to shrink it when that class is added.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.header').addClass('shrinkIt');
  } else {
    $('.header').removeClass('shrinkIt');
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.header.shrinkIt {
  padding: 20px 100px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.content {
  background: #2b2b99;
  height: 1400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    I will shrink.
  </div>

  <div class="content">



  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there also a way to let its content shrink with it?

Comment: Content of just the header? Or the whole page?

Comment: The image in it and the navigation buttons

Comment: You need to use selectors like `.header.shrinkIt .navigation-button` and reduce their `font-size` or other values.

Comment: Thx worked perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can have a [scroll event](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) handler on the window object that toggles a class on the body of the document. Then from CSS you set the design to look as you want it. As for smoothness, jQuery has an [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to be cross browser, but usually you do it with [CSS transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

You can see that the site you gave as example does this because you scroll and the class of the header element changes to 'short'. You can find their code in custom.js:

```
// Scroll to top
    jQuery(window).scroll(function ()
    {
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100)
        {
            jQuery('header.navbar').toggleClass('short', true);
            jQuery('.scrollup').fadeIn(300);
            jQuery('.scrollup-jobs').fadeIn(300);
        }
        else
        {
            jQuery('header.navbar').toggleClass('short', false);
            jQuery('.scrollup').fadeOut(1000);
            jQuery('.scrollup-jobs').fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

make 2 css classes and one of them with new class. I am taking `.smaller` as a new class like this

**CSS**

```
.navigation{
  /*css for larger navigation*/
}

.navigation.smaller{
  /*css for smaller navigation*/
}
```

You need to write css for both the conditions and then apply a bit of jquery

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowScrol = $('html, body').scrollTop();
        if(windowScrol>=100){ //scroll value can be changed accordingly
            $('.navigation').addClass('smaller');
        } else {
            $('.navigation').removeClass('smaller');
        };
    });
});
```

> Above jquery will detect if you scroll window to 100px it will add class to navigation and css is already there for it.